# CDI Flyway with multiple database vendor

Tags: java, flyway

Flyway provides framework which will execute migrations based on directory
/data/migration

My application supports Oracle, SQLServer or MySQL, i would like to keep scripts as /data/migration/oracle and /data/migration/sqlserver etc...

Application can be deployed either on Oracle, SQLServer or MySQL. How to inform Flyway framework to use specific database deployment migrations using spring integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will pass different location for each database. You may have placeholder for that. I have it done in maven plugin ond only what is needed to be changed is

```
<locations>
   <location>db/${database.type}</location>
</locations>
```